# How to avoid missing chrome history due to duplicate urls?

Tags: google-chrome, history

Chrome does not show complete browsing history, it only shows unique urls. How do I view complete usage history?

This is what I did:

- I entered google.com at 3 PM,
- then waited 5 minutes,
- opened google.com again.

When I open history now, even using [history 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-2/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp) extension  and [better history](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb) extension, there is no entry for google.com at 3 PM in the history.

How do I see complete log of my browsing history including repeated urls?

Comment: A screenshot may help......

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about an extension that does this for you, but you can use [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to browse through the history database of Chrome, which includes all visits, including duplicates.

1. Download and install [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)
2. Close Chrome (because Chrome locks its history database)
3. Open SQLite Browser
4. Press "Open Database"
5. Insert "C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" into address bar or browse to it. (If you use a profile, choose your profile)
6. Choose "All Files" on the bottom right (Chrome does not use an extension for its history database so it does not appear by default)
7. Open file "History".
8. Click on tab "Execute SQL"
9. Copy and paste this SQL query*:

   > `SELECT
   >   datetime(visit_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch') as time, urls.title, urls.url
   >   FROM visits
   >   INNER JOIN urls ON visits.url = urls.id
   >   ORDER BY visit_time DESC`

This will show you all visits you ever made, so if you want to limit your results, you can add `WHERE time [< or >] '[year]-[month]-[day] [hour]:[minute]:[second]` beneath the line with INNER JOIN, but above the line with ORDER BY.
For example `WHERE time > '2016-02-03 14:00:00'` for all visits after 14:00 today.
You can also use BETWEEN, for example `WHERE time BETWEEN '2016-02-03 12:00:00' AND '2016-02-03 14:00:00'` for all visits between 12:00 and 14:00 today.

* Chrome uses a different timestamp than SQL itself uses, so I use a custom function to convert the timestamp to date and time. The original query is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26118615/3094937). I edited the query to show the title and url by using an INNER JOIN with the urls table.

Comment: I've tried this extension, which exports to CSV or JSON, and it shows URLs including duplicates: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-chrome-history/dihloblpkeiddiaojbagoecedbfpifdj

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To get the visit times as local time instead of UNC, you should include the parameter `'localtime'`, like `datetime(visit_time / 1000000 + (strftime('%s', '1601-01-01')), 'unixepoch', 'localtime')` or `datetime(last_visit_time / 1000000 - 11644473600, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing at the consequences of unique URLs. Sometimes I browse for the best program to meet some specific requirement. If I revisit my browsing I don't want a link missing just because I had gone there a week later. Or if I don't know the date I found some tool or page and I ask myself what alternatives I had looked at, I won't find them. I wasn't really consciously aware of this.

So there are situations you'd want to look at the complete history log. With the extension **History Trends Unlimited** you can do this. The name is misleading, or not? I wonder how many people actually look at their own trends

Anyhow, I hope my tip helps.